# Keeping users uploaded documents private

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file, security, file-upload

I believe this question is platform/technology independent, however I am using Ruby on Rails with the carrierwave gem.

Users upload documents to my site, and I need to keep them private. I am exploring the different options available to me, along with their advantages and disadvantages.

Option 1

Obfuscate urls to images to make them impossible to guess.

This would be relatively simple to implement and fast to serve up. However, if a url was made public by whatever means, security is lost.

Option 2

Have documents accessed through some sort of intermediate step that requires authentication. This would have improved security over option 1, but would place additional load on the server. A page containing previews of a number of uploaded documents would hammer the server.

Are there any other options available to me? Have I made any mistakes with my claims, or missed any important points?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option you have is to have a "key" for your documents. You can generate a key, with a certain lifetime, and when you go on `/document/name/access_key`, you find the record matching and return the file associated with the record. Never exposing the real URL.